# Why would wifi router suddenly start having a bad connection for only one of the connected devices?

Tags: router, wireless-router, ping, modem, wifi-configuration

My home connection consists of two OSX Mavericks laptops connected to a Motorola box that functions both as a wifi router and a cable modem.

About a month ago, we started seeing problems. The internet on one random laptop would suddenly become veeeery slow or dead while the other laptop would be fine. That laptop would remain in that bad state until we'd turn its wifi off then back on to reconnect to the router.

I setup scripts to ping the router in several ways: my laptop to router's internal ip (192.168.0.1) my laptop to router's external ip (home connection ip visible to the internet) my laptop to one of my servers somewhere out there on the internet same server to router's external ip

I noticed that the ping to my router's internal and external ip would be solid and very fast while my internet connection was good.

Then suddenly, the ping to the router's external ip timed out 100% of the time and remained that way while the ping to the internal ip was unaffected. At the same time, the ping to the server started experiencing heavy but not 100% ping timeouts.

This doesn't make sense to me because if the ping to the router's external ip fails 100% of the time, why should pinging further hops on the internet fail less than 100% of the time?

Finally, the ping from the server to the router's external ip did not show any disruptions, which makes sense given that the other laptop was not experiencing connectivity problems during this time.

Any theories as to what's wrong with this modem+router device?